# What is Arka Vivaha?

Tags: marriage

Recently I heard of a concept named Arka Vivaha. I heard this concept in context of marriage. Can anyone please elaborate this concept and significance of it?

Comment: Hey why are you speaking about me? Lol haha, just kidding. This site might help - https://virendrabattu.wordpress.com/category/vedic-astrology/arka-vivah/

Comment: @Arka Please answer instead of sharing link. That will be helpful for the community.

Comment: I don't know the answer, neither do I have any scriptural sources for it.

Answer (score 1):

It is the marriage mainly intended at the third one to avoid the maleficiousness of that which is barred fo r humans.now it is performing for ghotaka brahmacharis, first time also.marriage with arka vriksha with usual sequence with pravara.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Please cite authentic hindu scriptural sources! It is rule of the forum!